# Cocoa touch - UIAnimation question

Tags: iphone, cocoa, touch

Hey guys, I still haven't found an answer to this so I think I'll ask you.

```
[viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[viewOggetto.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:viewOggetto.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

this is a simple animation for a view to appear in a position and then go full screen.
My question is: how can I make the content of the view follow the animation as well?
Now I have the view frame animating correctly but everything that is inside the view just appears fullscreen instantly.

Thanks.

Comment: `aFrame` is a method that I'm not familiar with. Are you sure you don't mean `[viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];`?

Comment: Oggetto is Italian, right? Don't you think it would be good to have English names for your variables rather than mixing English and Italian?

Comment: You are right about your first comment, what I meant is    [viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame]; also yes, Oggetto is an Italian name, but it is required for the context I am working with.

Comment: @Erik B It doesn't matter what language the variables are in. If an Italian developer or team is working on any code it is going to help them a lot more to manage it.

Comment: Just so you don't miss it below -Also remember that if you want UILabels scaled as well you cant just increase the frame size, you have to also increase the UILabel font size as well which UIView animation wasn't designed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but what viewOggetto exactly is? if it's a UIView then why to call viewOggetto.view?

is it a UIViewController? 
You call both :

```
[viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];
[viewOggetto.view setFrame:aFrame];
```

assuming it's a UIViewController, try this / prova cosi':

```
[self.view addSubview:viewOggetto.view]; // you need to have it before to animate it

// initial state of the animation:
[viewOggetto.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 240, 1, 1)]; // zoom from center
// viewOggetto.view.alpha = 0;   // eventually to add a fadeIn animation

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
// ending state of animation:
// viewOggetto.view.alpha = 1;   // restore to 1 to eventually to add a fadeIn animation
[viewOggetto.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

if it's a UIView just delete ".view" in every "viewOggetto.view" code

ciao,
luca

Comment: grazie Luca. I tried the code you posted but nothing has changed. I still get the frame animating correctly but the contents aren't resizing accordingly during the animation. Maybe the problem could be that I am initializing my viewOggetto using a NIB file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want to happen instead of it appearing full-screen instantly.  You mean you want it to fade in?  Set the `alpha` property on the subview to `0` and add it to `self.view` before you start the animation.  Then set the `alpha` property to 1 within the animation.

Comment: Nope. I initially set a smaller frame: [viewOggetto aFrame]; then I want the view to go fullscreen in 0.5 seconds. But with the code I posted, I get the view's frame to behave correctly, but the view's content doesn't follow this 'zooming' animation and just goes full screen. I am wondering how can I make the content follow the animation aswell.

Comment: Add the subview with its initial frame before starting the animation.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my code wrong. the first instruction meant to be [viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];(edited it right now). Maybe now you understand what I meant in the first place.

Comment: And it still doesn't work?  Take away the animation altogether.  Is the view full-screen or in its initial size?  If it's full-screen, then check whether you are clipping to bounds or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Jim's answer. UIView animations animate UIViews from one context to another. If the context doesn't exist before the `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` then underside effects will happen. The context wont exist if the view hasn't been added to subview.

Comment: I edited the code; the first line is supposed to be [viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];

Comment: That wont change anything. If its not on screen when you call beginAnimation it won't be able to animate. You are adding the view to the screen after you call beginAnimation

Comment: Actually the animation is working. My problem is that only the view's frame is subject to the animation. What's inside the view (UILabels and such) just get fired on the screen during the animation. I was wondering how can I make the contents animating accordingly to the view's frame.

Comment: then change the view.bounds too, and set its property viewOggetto. autoresizesSubviews = YES;

Comment: @meronix: i tried the autoresizesSubviews without any luck. May be it could be because my view is initialized through a NIB file? also, I cannot understand why you told me to set the bounds. the dimensions i am willing to have at the start of the animation are set during the [viewOggetto setFrame:aFrame];. Maybe I am neglecting something.

Comment: just for what i read in xcode-help regarding autoresizesSubviews : autoresizesSubviews, 
A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver automatically resizes its subviews when its bounds change. - it may be probably the same for frame, but just to try...

Comment: @Rudriger: That is exactly my problem. I was thinking(maybe superficially) that the UIView animation had some tool to manage the scaling of the content during a 'zoom' animation. Maybe I got fooled by the simplicity to create simple animations using this method. Guess I will have to try some work around.

Comment: I don't think autoresideSubviews will work in this case. Have a look at CATransform3DScale but it will be harder to use then UIView animations. Also remember that if you want UILabels scaled as well you cant just increase the frame size, you have to also increase the font size as well which UIView animation wasn't designed to do.

Comment: Actually meronix might be right. Forgot where I used CATransform3DScale I was scaling a 3d object. CGAffineTransformMakeScale might be better.

Comment: I resolved using the CGAffineTransformMakeScale. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction guys.

Comment: Although this wasn't a straight answer why dont you reward the people that helped you.